# Загрузка файлов с другого сервера Curl PHP

Tags: php, curl

На другом сервере где лежит файл mp4, ещё стоит запрет, получение только через куки.
Проблема с куками решена, но файл по какой-то причине не получается скопировать к себе на сервер.

```
$dest_file = @fopen("/new_file.mp4", "w");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site.uz/video/2020-02-27/1080p.mp4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://site.uz/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $dest_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ROOT . '/data/sessions/cookie.txt');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$error = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($dest_file);
```

В `$result` возвращается 1, в `$error` 0, поэтому не понятно почему не скачивается. Куки точно подходят, проверено.

Возможно есть другой способ копирования файла?

Сохраняется файл 195 кб. всего и не открывается, не понятно почему.

P.S.: видео файл большой, целый фильм.

Comment: Так а что внутри файла, что за содержимое? Может там и содержится указание на то, что пошло не так? Это видео файл, или можно его открыть в текстовом редакторе и увидеть что-то читаемое?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Вы правы, почему я сразу не догадался, там написано `<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, добавил:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "login:password");
```

Все таки не проходил авторизацию просто через отправку файла с куками, а нужно была повторная авторизация.